# Can't validate signature value using certificate public key provided in an xml (X509Certificate2)

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, x509certificate2, xml-signature

I spent 100s of hours researching this subject, and other senior programmer who coded the original project also could not make it work. I have an xml with a parameter of SignatureValue, Certificate (X509Certificate2) and Digest Value. The created and given Signature value stated in the same xml was made by converting concatinated fields (equal to Digest Value) into a hash (SHA1), then encrypted via private key. Private key is taken out of the certificate for privacy and I only have the Public key within. Now, no matter how I code around it, I always get a false value back (as in VerifyHash/verifyHashResult is false). Here is the code I am using:

// Need your help please.

```
 static void VerifyHash(string sigVal , string digestVal, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            sigValInBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sigVal);
            try
            {
 using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProviderDecrypt = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key)
               {
// Line below always return value of FALSE no matter how I code it. Here I want to verify the hashed freshly calculated digest value that is now hashed with the signature value
                    rsaProviderDecrypt.Decrypt(sigValInBytes, false);

                   rsaProviderDecrypt.Dispose();
               }
             }
        }


// At the main program I get the certificate from the xml given and call the method above:

main
{
// Code below gets the certificate details from a given xml, details of each variable confirmed to be accurate.
char[] Base64_x509ByteArray;
Base64_x509ByteArray = t.DigitalSignatures.First().X509Data.ToCharArray();
byte[] x509ByteArray;
x509ByteArray = Convert.FromBase64CharArray(Base64_x509ByteArray, 0, Base64_x509ByteArray.Length);

// Here am creating the certificate from the gathered data/certificate:
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(x509ByteArray);

VerifyHash(t.DigitalSignatures.FirstOrDefault().SignatureValue.Trim(), concatenatedFieldValues, cert);

}
```

Comment: What's that `ByteConverter` class doing? Why is the signature & digest a `string`?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use `X509Certificate2` ? Could give you another suggestion?

Comment: For question  #1, I went ahead and made some changes and removed the byte conversion because I don't need for the new code posted just now. I think I am a step closer, and doing the correct thing in useing rsaProviderDecrypt.Decrypt(sigValInBytes, false) especially after converting sigVal to bytes array using FromBase64String because that made the byte array no bigger than 256 in size. But getting a new error "Key does not exist"

Comment: For question #2: I have to go with X509Certificate because that is what vendors use to encrypt the digital signature with (I have no choice here).

Comment: Any ideas why I am getting the new error "Key not found"?

Comment: A public key can't be used for decryption. (While the signature verify formula involves running a process similar to decryption, different padding/verification rules are in play, and you need to use the matching verb).

Answer (score 1):

Some shots in the dark:

1. Find the piece that is broken: Try doing the entire "encrypt / hash check" process in code without transfering anything over XML.  If you can hash a string locally, and the hashes match, then the problem is in XML. Otherwise, the problem is in the cert or decryptor.
2. If the problem is on the cert / encryptor side, try hash matching with a local .NET cryptography class.  If that fails, the problem is an encryption setting. Otherwise, it is the cert.
3. BIG shot in the dark: The call to `Dispose` right after the hash check.  It **shouldn't** matter, but that caused an issue while I was decrypting using the Rijndael algorithm. Best guess was the optimizer was closing the stream early or something weird like that.  Moving the constructor out of the `using` statement and manually calling `Dispose` after accessing the result fixed that "optimization".
4. Might try a reversable encryption algorithm. [Rinjdael](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael(v=vs.110).aspx) is native to .NET, and is reversable.  Good for debug and proof of concept work. (Note: it uses Time as part of the salt, so RJ doesn't match hashes, it decrypts. So not good for passwords in Production environments.)
5. If the XML is the cause, check the encodings. Encryption is very sensitive to encodings, and XML serializers are finnicky beasts to begin with. The strings may *look* the same, but represented differently, or extra control characters added. Sql Server nvarchars are UCS-2, varchars are iso-8859-1, C# strings are utf-8, etc.  Easy for encodings to mis-match, and an encoding change would easily cause this. Try converting the original value to `utf-16` before inserting into the Xml, and set the Xml Declaration Encoding to `utf-16`. Just to be safe.
6. Note about NotePad: if you have opened the Xml in Notepad to take a quick look or edit, and saved it, there are probably extra "end of line" characters on your strings now.  If you did the same in Word... oh my...  Might want to try an original copy.
7. Failing that, try generating new encrypted values and see if they match.

Comment: Thank you so much for the points above, I am considering some points, in fact I made an update to my code and coded a decrpt call (posted in the original code above), but now I have a new error "Key not found" although I am positive that the key has been extracted and is there (see my updated code above). Thanks.